# Sails js and Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sequelize.js, waterline

I'm learning Node.js and Sails is my framework of choice.
I want to use it in a project with MySql db and I think that Sequelize Orm is more complete.
How can I use Sequelize Orm in Sails instead of Waterline?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you can as sails was born with sequelize.

You can read [Mike McNeil's answer here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sailsjs/jmR36bD-Zys/-F0ZFy1Q1IoJ) and maybe ask Mike directly if he will reintroduce sequelize support

Answer (score 2):

There are two project that come out recently that i've have worked to reintroduce full support to sequelize, including blueprints.

sails-hook-sequelize

sails-hook-sequelize-blueprints

[See my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31768186/3683121)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ npm install sails-hook-sequelize
$ npm install sails-hook-sequelize-blueprints
$ npm install sequelize
$ npm install pg pg-hstore
$ npm install continuation-local-storage
```

.sailsrc

```
"hooks": {
    "blueprints": false,
    "orm": false,
    "pubsub": false
}
```

In connections.js

```
somePostgresqlServer: {
    user: 'postgres',
    password: '',
    database: 'database',
    options: {
        host   : 'localhost',
        port   : 5432,
        logging: true
   }
}
```

In model folder

// for example let take userstable ->users.js

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    firstname: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    secondname: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
  }

  }
};
```

or another method for connection create seperate file db.js

```
   module.exports = {
 dbPath: function () {
  return ("postgres://postgres:(user)@localhost:5432/(databasename)");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you must intsall pakage sails-hook-sequelize:

```
npm install sails-hook-sequelize --save
```

Seconds edit file .sailsrc

```
 "hooks": {
  "orm": false,
  "pubsub": false
}
```

file ./config/models.js

```
module.exports.models = {
    schema: true,
    connection: 'mysql',
    migrate: 'safe'
};
```

file ./config/connections.js

```
module.exports.connections = {
   mysql: {
        adapter: 'sails-mysql',
        port: 3306,
        user: 'root',
        password: '123456',
        database: 'TestDataBase',
        charset: 'utf8',
        collation: 'utf8-general_ci',
        options: {
            host: 'localhost'
        }
    }
};
```

define models in ./api/models/UserAccount.js

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        ID: {
            type: Sequelize.BIGINT(20),
            autoIncrement: true,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        UID: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(255),
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
        },
        UserName: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(50),
            allowNull: true
        }
    },
    associations: function() {},
    options: {
        tableName: 'UserAccount',
        createdAt: 'CreatedDate',
        updatedAt: 'ModifiedDate',
        hooks: {}
}
};
```

Final, use model:

```
UserAccount.findAll({}).then(function(success){}, function(err){
})
```

Good luck ^^.

Comment: Our project was started year ago, but now we need to move on sequelize. Can I use both of them in parallel before refactoring be done?