# How to initialize a Sequalize object with already defined connections config

Tags: sails.js, sequelize.js

I have the `connections` and `models` config files setup + the models. Similar to [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31768186/1430394), and now I need to use a `sequelize` object reference in my controller, f.e. to make raw queries `sequelize.query()` or the Sequelize functions (`sequelize.fn(...)`), but how can I initialize it? All I could find in [the docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/getting-started/) was how to setup the DB connection completely anew, and I don't need that, because I already have the connection set up and working.

If I `require('sequelize')` in my controller, then I need to initialize an object, with anew DB parameters (host, username, pswd, etc.). I need just to use a Sequelize object reference of the existing connection, which was setup in the config files. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 'connection' module which exports the sequelize object and then require that module where you need it

dbConnection.js

```
...
module.exports = new Sequelize(dbname, null, null, sequelizeOptions)
```

anyfile.js

```
var db = require(pathToDbConnection.js)
db.query(...)
```