# Use multiple datastore connections with Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sequelize.js

I've defined 2 connections in the `/config/connections.js` file:

```
  monolithMysql: {
    user: 'store_app',
    database: 'store',
    dialect: 'mysql',
    options: {
      dialect: 'mysql',
      host: 'dockerhost',
      port: 3306,
      logging: console.log
    }
  },

  postgres: {
    user: 'user_app',
    database: 'user_authentication',
    dialect: 'postgres',
    options: {
      dialect: 'postgres',
      host: 'dockerhost',
      port: 8201,
      logging: console.log
    }
  }
```

and in the different models I've put the property `connection`, so that they're distinguished, as follows:

```
module.exports = {

  options: {
    connection: 'monolithMysql', // or 'postgres' in other models.
    ...
```

In `/config/models.js` I set as default connection the `monolithMysql` one. But that should be overridden by the `connection` property, if specified, in the models. *If I comment out or do not specify the `connection` property in `/config/models.js` then Sequelize hook fails to load.*

Nevertheless, when trying to query models that have `postgres` as connection, it still queries them in the MySQL DB, and fails... If I set `postgres` as default connection, then it will always query in that DB, no matter what the local `connection` property of the different models says.

Any suggestions how to setup 2 connections at the same time?

Update: found out that it initializes only 1 instance of Sequelize - an instance with the default connection, specified in `/config/models.js`

Comment: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/263 Maybe this conversation can help you.

Comment: I saw this and wanted to try out but the problem is that so far I've been setting up Sequelize only through the `sails-hook-sequelize` with `/config/connections.js`. And I don't know where/which file to define and call `new Sequelize`, in order to call the the 2 connections, before Sails is lifted. Tried with `/config/bootstrap.js` but did not work as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I ended up writing an upgrade to [`sails-hook-sequelize`](https://github.com/festo/sails-hook-sequelize) to support multiple database connection instances simultaneously.

The pull-request hasn't been reviewed at this point (13 April '16), but it has passed all tests and CI checks, so no worries. (the owner of the repo seems to be neglecting PR reviews in the last couple of months).

**You can find [the pull-request here](https://github.com/festo/sails-hook-sequelize/pull/22).**

In order to require the module, along with the multiple db connections upgrade, in your `package.json` file, just write:

```
"sails-hook-sequelize": "git@github.com:galioy/sails-hook-sequelize.git#f0c0c5d72ee97ac5504e6f3a0825e37c3587909a"
```

The configuration is the basic one, as you would do it normally for Sequelize:

1. add connections configurations to `/config/connections.js` (see OP)
2. for each model that you want to use secondary connection - just add
   the name of the connection to `options.connection` property in the model itself (see
   OP).

For detailed explanation, see the main comment of the [pull-request](https://github.com/festo/sails-hook-sequelize/pull/22).